# Creating project in Django using pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm a beginner in python3. I'm using pycharm in windows10 and i'm using the book 'Python Crash Course'. 
I already activated virtual environment and installed Django.

These are the following commands that is written in the book:

```
(ll_env)learning_log$ django-admin.py startproject learning_log
(ll_env)ls learning_log ll_env manage.py`enter code here`
(ll_env)ls learning_log __init__.py settings.py wsgi.py
```

But PyCharm does not recognize the "ls" part. 
Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

use `dir` instead of using `ls` when you're using command prompt or the integrated terminal in pycharm on windows OS.
`ls` is a unix command.

Comment: I also tried using dir. the book said that it should create the 'manage.py' but it did not. any solutions to this?

Comment: Directory of C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django\ll_env

07/03/2020  02:56 PM    <DIR>          .
07/03/2020  02:56 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/03/2020  02:56 PM    <DIR>          Include
07/03/2020  02:56 PM    <DIR>          Lib
07/03/2020  02:56 PM               120 pyvenv.cfg
07/03/2020  02:58 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
               1 File(s)            120 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django

File Not Found

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `django-admin.py startproject learning_log .` write `django-admin startproject learning_log .`

And you should not write `(ll_env)ls learning_log __init__.py settings.py wsgi.py`. These files will be shown after you create a new project and use `dir` instead of `ls`

I hope it'll help you